# Visual Studio C++: AdditionalIncludeDirectories relative to external project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a project in Visual Studio that depends on a second project from another solution. I have set it up this way because the second project is a library that I want to use in multiple independent solutions.

I need to add the external project directory to my AdditionalIncludeDirectories. I could hard code this path, but then if I moved the library solution I would have to update both the project reference and the AdditionalIncludeDirectories. Is there a way to set up the AdditionalIncludeDirectories so that it is relative to the external project directory?

For example, $(ProjectDir) is a macro for the current project directory. Is there something I can use that is basically $(MyExternalProjectDir)?

Comment: It already works that way when you "hard-code" it, the IDE transforms it into a relative path.  Try it, look in the .vcxproj file afterwards.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure if I'm understanding you, it did not seem to work. In my main project under Properties > C/C++ > AdditionalIncludeDirectories I tried adding the path "$(SolutionDir)\..\NPP Utils\NPP Utils\src". This expands into an absolute path to my shared project. This builds, but I don't see any automatic transformation. In the .vcxproj file The AdditionalIncludeDirectories field is exactly as I typed it, even after I restarted Visual Studio. I also tried typing the absolute path to the shared library, and got the same thing. So I'm not seeing any transformation.

Comment: That's not really "hard-coded" like c:\foo\bar.  You already used a relative path, should be just fine as-is although it isn't necessary.  Most important detail is that a maintainer can check this solution out from source control five years from now and still get a clean build.  That does tend to require either good project documentation or checking-in NPP as well.  Since nobody usually knows how to find the docs back by then, or find the right version of NPP, you do tend to favor the latter.

Comment: I also tried an absolute path like that.